# Every real matrix with non-negative entries has a non negative eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $A$ is any matrix $n\times n$ with non negative entries, then $A$ has a non negative eigenvalue.

I know that I have to use the Brower Point fix theorem, but I am not finding the function for that. Could any one help me?

Thanks!